# Attribute providers FirebaseInitProvider and FacebookInitProvider from AndroidManifest also present at AndroidManifest

Tags: android, gradle, manifest

My application was composed of only one `application` module. I recently tried to split it into 2 modules (a `feature` base and a `application` apk one) in order to add later an `instant-app` module.

My newly created `feature` module's `AndroidManifest` and `gradle.build` contain everything that was inside the previous `application` module ones:

`feature` **AndroidManifest :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="base.package" 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- all uses-permissions and permissions -->    

    <application>

        <!-- activities, intent-filters... -->

        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider663###########"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"/>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

        <!-- etc -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

`application` **AndroidManifest :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="app.package" 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</manifest>
```

`feature` **build.gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
             // debug values
        }
        release {
             // release values
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
        versionCode rootProject.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.versionName
    }

    baseFeature true
}

dependencies {
    api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLib"
    application project(':apk')
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$rootProject.gmsLib"
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
    // other dependencies
}
```

`application` **build.gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.package"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdk
        versionCode rootProject.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.versionName

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":feature")
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

However, although everything builds fine, I have a problem with my APK run configuration:

[image]

When I select *Default Activity* in Launch Options, I get a *Default Activity not found* warning , and when I select a specific one, I get a *The Activity 'XXXX' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml* one.

After some research, I realized this is because of an error with the `apk`  Manifest, that I was able to find by looking at the "Merged Manifest" option. Here is the output:

[image]

I couldn't find relevant information to help me about this issue... thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this issue by adding `tools:node="replace"` in the `<application>` node of the feature's `AndroidManifest`. Also, don't forget to add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` at Manifest top-level.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add these providers in your base module and feature module to fix merge manifest error.

```
<provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="{$applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:exported="(check library provider have exported value true or false)"
        tools:node="replace"/>
<provider
        android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider"
        android:authorities="{$applicationId}.FacebookInitProvider"
        android:exported="(check library provider have exported value true or false)"
        tools:node="replace"/>
```